# Is it possible to use both cheaper and emperor with uWSGI

Tags: python, django, wsgi, uwsgi

I need to host multiple `Django` sites (quite a lot of sites actually) and currently I am using `Apache`+`mod_wsgi` but I want to switch to `uWSGI`.

One of the nice features of `uWSGI` is `cheaper mode` that spawns processes as needed and shuts them down as needed as well. On the other hand, it seems that the way to make it run multiple sites is to use `emperor mode`.

Can `emperor mode` be used together with `cheaper` subsystem? Are there any quirks/problems I should be aware of? Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: You can run multiple uwsgi instances without emperor. On debian at least, it's just a matter of having multiple .ini files in `/etc/uwsgi/sites-enabled/`.

Answer (score 2):

There are no problems as each "vassal" can be configured with its special cheaper mode. In this way you can have QoS for your customers.